# Python Script not working on double click

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am not able to run a .py file by double clicking it. It just opens and closes.

What I have tried:

- Ran it in cmd with `"Python.exe path"`. Runs Smooth
- Ran it by running `"python"` in cmd. In python shell the file runs smooth.
- Updated environment variables then tried to double click it doesn't run.
- Right click, open with, set it to correct path of python, it doesn't run. Just opens and closes.

I tried - inserted a popup msg, made it write to a file, use input to make it pause. But nothing woks when I double click. just opens and closes. the file runs perfectly in cmd, python shell and spyder.

Please help... Any ideas would be helpful

python `version 3.6.1`

Script ---

```
from selectorlib import Extractor
import requests 

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

url = [r'1',r'2']

price_1 = 77990
price_2 = 89990



lst = []

for i in url:

    sample_extractor = 'C:/Users/Lappy/Documents/Python 3/Price Tracker/Laptop Price.yml'

    # Create an Extractor by reading from the YAML file
    e = Extractor.from_yaml_file(sample_extractor)

    # Download the page using requests
    r = requests.get(i)
    # Pass the HTML of the page and create 
    data = e.extract(r.text)
    # Print the data 
    # print(data)

    price = int(data['Price'][1:].replace(',',''))
    mrp = int(data['MRP'][1:].replace(',',''))
    disc = data['Discount'][:3].replace(',','')

    lst_temp = [price,mrp,disc]
    lst.append(lst_temp)

    print(price)
    print(mrp)
    print(disc)


output = ['prod1', price_1 - lst[0][0],'prod2', price_2 - lst[1][0]]

with open('C:\\Users\\Lappy\\Documents\\Python 3\\Price Tracker\\output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in output:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

Comment: Do other python files run if double-clicked?

Comment: Presumably, there's nothing in your code to keep the console window open, when the process terminates. Though that is impossible to tell without a [mcve].

Comment: @Justlearnedit 

I typed the following to test a file:

print('abc') 
temp = input('Enter')
print('abc') 
temp2 = input('Enter')

the first abc and input works is shown when i double click the file but when I press enter the 2nd abc doesn't print, it just closes

Comment: @IInspectable well I just tried by putting an input command before and after every line and then ran it. it opened the first input when i press enter it just closes. nothing happens.

Comment: if you want I can upload it to google drive and put a link of the file here.

Comment: Please read what [mcve] says, again, carefully.

Comment: works on an IDLE?

Comment: It's nearly impossible to solve this problem for you without reducing it down to a minimal reproducible example, about which you explain the required setup in complete detail. Then someone with mixed Python and native debugging experience can at least have a chance to analyze the problem.

Comment: One thing I can say is that your fourth attempt to use the "open with" dialog to "set it to correct path of python" is wrong in general. Browsing to "python.exe" creates a file association that doesn't support command line arguments and doesn't support Python's shell extension drop handler that lets one drop files on a script as arguments. In the open with dialog, you need to select the installed Python app, and select to always use it to run .py files. If you installed the launcher, the Python app that you should select will have a rocket on the icon.

Comment: Also, why are you stuck using Python 3.6.1? Generally in Windows there's no systemic reason to be stuck on an older version. That's typically a problem with code deployed on Linux servers. If you're using Python as a tool on a Windows workstation, you should try to stay up to date with the most recent version, which in this case is 3.8.x.

Comment: @ErykSun In the openwith I select the python.exe. It is just that I have multiple environments installed. so I select the python.exe application which I want to run on.

And I have 2.7 through 3.8 all of them installed. Never had such an issue. I will try with df.to_csv also once

Comment: @CoolCloud I do not have IDLE. I am using Anaconda so have jupyter and spyder. I will try in IDLE also

Comment: @IInspectable thanks going through the steps given there
May be they can help

Comment: @Anuj, to repeat, selecting "python.exe" in the "open with" dialog is *completely wrong*. The template command needs to have `%*`, and selecting "python.exe" *does not do this*.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this problem in windows. every time I double clicked on .py file, it just opened and closed a black window. then I realised that it is showing output in cmd but it is not holding the screen.

So I used below 3 methods to hold screen.

1. `input()` method at the end of script to hold screen

```
print('abc')
temp = input('Enter : ')
print(temp)
    
input()
```

2. `time` module to put screen on sleep

```
import time
        
print('abc')
temp = input('Enter : ')
print(temp)
        
#sleeping for 1 hour
time.sleep(3600)
```

3. `os` module to pause screen

```
import os
    
print('abc')
temp = input('Enter : ')
print(temp)
    
os.system("pause")
```

Comment: Hello there, I've suggested another edit to your answer which fixes your code formatting. Please don't enclose your whole post in a code block, as it makes your answers much harder to read. Before editing your answer again, please take a moment to read about how [code formatting](/editing-help#code) works on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` to the top of your file