# Python file does not work when executed by double click on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell

Hi there is an issue I cannot work my head around.
Basically the script works very fine when I execute it via Powershell/cmd `python ./myscript.py` but not when I double click on it.
I checked with a much simpler script to check if the issue was with my Windows/Python3 configuration.

```
import os
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('hello')
    os.system("PAUSE")
```

And this one works either by double click or by `python ./myscript.py`

I guess the issue is with my script but no error is returned and it works just as expected when launched in PS so I do not get it.
Would you guys have some debugging insights?

Similar to this old question: [Python Script not working on double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229347/python-script-not-working-on-double-click)

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing your code.

Comment: Aren't there comon reasons why the code would execute fine in a way and not the other? The code is infact quite long, I can try to make it shorter/anonymous and post it here. Thanks.

Comment: With the non-function script, what, specifically, happens when you double-click? Is it a GUI script (`.pyw`)? Examine the file associations, e.g. with `cmd /c ftype (cmd /c assoc .py).Split('=')[-1]`

Comment: It is a .py file (no GUI). When double clicking, it is oppened with python3.10.exe
.py files are associated to this program.

Comment: So what _doesn't_ work if you double-click? Note that double-clicking usually automatically closes the console window when the script terminates - you'd have to put code into it to keep the window open, such as waiting for a keystroke.

Comment: The python.exe terminal just open then closes automatically. Without the script being executed at all. I added system pauses to the script so the second point you're mentioning shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @Anders This simply isn't true. It's impossible to answer *for sure* what the problem is, but given the information provided by OP, a few *educated guesses* can be made, which may help solve the problem or get further information to help in doing so. E.g., we *know* the problem can't be some exception in their script, as it runs fine when run through Powershell. We *know* it can't be something concerning file binding, as another, simpler script runs fine with double click.

Answer (score 0):

###### Let's reiterate:

- The script works fine with `python .\myscript.py` in Powershell.
- The script closes instantly without anything being done when double-clicking it.
- A smaller script you tested works both with the console and double click.

###### This means:

- The problem isn't some exception thrown by your script.
- The problem isn't in the binding of Python to the .py extension.

But it's pretty hard to find out more when the script window isn't open long enough to see anything.
So, try just executing `.\myscript` (without `python`) in Powershell. This is equivalent to double clicking, but shows all output/errors.

Does this give you something along the lines of `Python could not be found.`?
If not, then hopefully the error shown will point you in the right direction.
If yes, you know this can't *really* be true, as `python .\myscript.py`works.
So, what *is* the problem?

**Do you have a shebang line at the start of your in the script?** Specifically, `#!/usr/bin/env python3`?
Try removing it, see if it works then.

###### Explanation:

On Linux, shebang lines help the OS know which program to run when doing `./myscript.py`.
On Windows, the registry already does file association and the content of the file is only evaluated by the program specified there, so a shebang line isn't strictly needed.
But, using the Python Launcher (`py.exe`), which is associated for .py files when installing Python on Windows by default, shebangs are evaluated and can be used e.g. to choose different Python installations or support arguments (`python -v .\myscript.exe`) on double click execution.
The problem is, if you use the *wrong* shebang, Python doesn't know how to deal with that. `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is such a wrong shebang.
This is because in Linux, `env` is used similar to `$Path` in Windows. So it's a pointer to one "default" installation of Python. The advantage of using `env` is that it's independent from installation path. The disadvantage is, that there is only one default.
So, what *does* work?

###### In my testing, the following work on Windows:

- `#!/usr/bin/env python` (Best choice imo)
- `#!/usr/bin/python`
- `#!/usr/bin/python3`
- `#! python`